# What does the "Hidden Article" icon on KnowledgeBase articles mean?

Tags: documentation

While reviewing another SSE question that linked to [this KB page](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/583017), I noticed in the top-right corner of the page's main content section that there was a little icon labeled "hidden article". What exactly does this mean? Does this article simply not display in search results? Is there a known reason for making an article hidden (e.g. the article isn't complete yet, etc.)?

[image]

Comment: Ironically, this label only shows when you are actually logged in. As anonymous, it doesn't show.

Comment: Mark you are right, but this label appear just for this article. I din't find it on other KB pages.

Comment: Yeah, that is interesting, Mark. I wonder why that only displays to authenticated (non-anonymous) visitors.

Comment: Seems to me only Sitecore representatives can answer. Or it just that they forgot to remove the label after publishing the page. It may acts as a tag for the author to know that it is not ready for viewing. Though, anonymous users fo not see it

Comment: Yeah, you might be right @HishaamNamooya. I'll reach out to Sitecore Support and ask them if they can provide some details. I'll post an answer with their response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The label is indeed for unlisted articles (articles that are accessible, but only if you have the link). We sometimes use it for soft launches if it doesn't matter too much that the info is discovered.

That particular article shouldn't be hidden; PSS (Product Support Services) are fixing that now.

The fact that logged-in users can see it and anonymous users can't is a bug and has been reported.

Thank you for raising it!

Comment: Thanks so much, Martina! I was actually just about to message you in Sitecore Slack before raising the issue to Sitecore Support! :)

Comment: No problem! The ever vigilant Mr. Cassidy alerted me to the question. :)

Comment: Seems i got near to the answer :)